# How to [set meson configure source and build directory] and [specify bin path for meson setup]?

Tags: linux, build, kde-plasma, meson-build

I'm trying to build latest kde desktop on debian stable(bullseye).

A component build failed: WaylandProtocols

Here is what I did:

```bash
# prepare the folders
sudo mkdir -p /opt/kde-desktop/{deps,app,etc}
sudo chown -R build: /opt/kde-desktop
mkdir -p ~/deps

# libxslt(wayland need it)
sudo apt install python3.9-dev
wget -O ~/deps/libxslt.tar.xz https://download.gnome.org/sources/libxslt/1.1/libxslt-1.1.37.tar.xz
tar -xvf ~/deps/libxslt.tar.xz
mv ~/deps/libxslt-* ~/deps/libxslt
rm -rf ~/deps/libxslt.tar.xz
mkdir -p ~/deps/libxslt-build
cd ~/deps/libxslt-build
../libxslt/configure --prefix=/opt/kde-desktop/deps
make -j$(nproc)
make install

# xmlto (wayland need it)
apt install xmlto

# build wayland(WaylandProtocols need it)
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland.git ~/deps/wayland
export WLD=/opt/kde-desktop/deps
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$WLD/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$WLD/etc
export PATH=$WLD/bin:$PATH
meson setup ~/deps/wayland ~/deps/wayland-build --prefix=$WLD --libdir=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH --sysconfdir=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
ninja -C ~/deps/wayland-build
ninja -C ~/deps/wayland-build install
cd ..

# build WaylandProtocols failed
latestWaylandProtocolsLink=$(curl -s https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/api/v4/projects/2891/releases/| jq -r '.[0].assets.sources[0].url')
waylandProtocolsRelease=$(curl -s https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/api/v4/projects/2891/releases/| jq -r '.[0].name')
wget -P ~/deps "$latestWaylandProtocolsLink"
unzip -d ~/deps ~/deps/wayland-protocols-"$waylandProtocolsRelease".zip
rm -rf ~/deps/wayland-protocols-"$waylandProtocolsRelease".zip
mv ~/deps/wayland-protocols-"$waylandProtocolsRelease" ~/deps/wayland-protocols
cd ~/deps/wayland-protocols
meson setup ~/deps/wayland-protocols ~/deps/wayland-protocols-build --prefix=/opt/kde-desktop/deps --libdir=/opt/kde-desktop/deps/lib --sbindir=/opt/kde-desktop/deps/bin
ninja -C build
ninja -C build install
```

I can use meson setup to set source and build directory, but WaylandProtocols needs higher version of wayland-scanner which have been built by wayland in `/opt/wayland/bin` and I have specified in command line for meson setup.

Why the specified option not working?

```bash
$ meson setup ~/deps/wayland-protocols ~/deps/wayland-protocols-build --prefix=/opt/kde-desktop/deps --libdir=/opt/kde-desktop/deps/lib --bindir=/opt/kde-desktop/deps/bin
Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/opt/wayland/etc'
Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/opt/wayland/etc'
The Meson build system
Version: 0.56.2
Source dir: /home/build/deps/wayland-protocols
Build dir: /home/build/deps/wayland-protocols-build
Build type: native build
Project name: wayland-protocols
Project version: 1.31
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Configuring wayland-protocols.pc using configuration
Configuring wayland-protocols-uninstalled.pc using configuration
Program scan.sh found: YES (/home/build/deps/wayland-protocols/tests/scan.sh)
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.2)
Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/opt/wayland/etc'
Dependency wayland-scanner found: NO found 1.18.0 but need: '>=1.20.0'
Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.18.4)
Build-time dependency wayland-scanner found: NO (tried cmake)

../home/build/deps/wayland-protocols/tests/meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Invalid version of dependency, need 'wayland-scanner' ['>=1.20.0'] found '1.18.0'.

A full log can be found at /home/build/deps/wayland-protocols-build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

---

Here is the official doc about meson configure: https://mesonbuild.com/Configuring-a-build-directory.html

It says: 'You invoke meson configure by giving it the location of your build dir. If omitted, the current working directory is used instead.'

It's example:

```
Source dir /home/jpakkane/clangdemo/2_address
Build dir  /home/jpakkane/clangdemo/2_address/buildmeson
```

I follow the guide but always get the warning that build directory is missing:

```bash
~/deps/wayland-protocols $ meson configure --prefix=/opt/kde-desktop/deps ~/deps/wayland-protocols
WARNING: The source directory instead of the build directory was specified.
WARNING: Only the default values for the project are printed, and all command line parameters are ignored.

Core properties:
  Source dir /home/build/deps/wayland-protocols
```

If I don't want to cd to the source nor build directory and then run meson configure, how can I set build directory if I use `meson configure`?